# excel 2010 - listobject table and worksheet range return different values - bug?

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I have a table (table of listobject type).  I sorted it, filtered it and viewed the sheet.  All is well.  Now I attempt to enumerate...

Where

- oWs_ma is the worksheet that contains the table
- oLO_maTable is the table on that worksheet
- oRg are range objects
- all vars are strings

In the loop below, the temporary range object returns the correct row number.  This row number is the number the sheet shows.  For example, the 1st data row in the table lies on sheet row 5.  In all but one single row, out of many, worksheet and table objects return identical values.  In the single instance where they do not, the worksheet is correct.  Just one error in 30 or 40 rows.  This is not an end point error.  It happens midway in the table.  There appears to be nothing unique before the error.  In fact, the row value reported by oRg_tmp.row changes and points to the correct row!

Is this construct correct?  There is additional code include for testing purposes, just to show that what I am getting is indeed "right"

```
For Each oRg_tmp In oLO_maTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

  Set oRg_maOwer = oLO_maTable.Range.Cells(oRg_tmp.row, colndx_ma_it_owner)
  Set oRg_maGLDept = oLO_maTable.Range.Cells(oRg_tmp.row, colndx_ma_gl_dept)

  ma_owner = oRg_maOwer.Value2
  ma_gl_dept = oRg_maGLDept.Value2
  ma_owner_ws = oWs_ma.Cells(oRg_tmp.row, colndx_ma_it_owner).Value2
  ma_gl_dept_ws = oWs_ma.Cells(oRg_tmp.row, colndx_ma_gl_dept).Value2

  ...
Next
```

If the construct is correct, this is solved.  I will use the worksheet.

Thanks.